# error com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.UnknownHostException: abcd-local.us.company

Tags: java, spring-boot, netflix-eureka

I have executed my eureka registry service successfully, When I am executing my other service to register it with my eureka registry I am getting below exception

**ERROR

```
com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient - Request execution error
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.UnknownHostException:  abcd-local.us.company**
at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:187) ~[jersey-apache-client4-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.GZIPContentEncodingFilter.handle(GZIPContentEncodingFilter.java:123) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.netflix.discovery.EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.handle(EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.java:27) ~[eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.get(WebResource.java:509) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.getApplicationsInternal(AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.java:194) ~[eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.getApplications(AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.java:165) ~[eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137) ~[eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.java:73) ~[eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
    at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:928) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1323) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1276) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1192) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1126) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:45) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.resolveHostname(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:263) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
14:19:51.550 [main]
```

```
ERROR com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient - DiscoveryClient_OTHER-SERVICE/A123321.AP.SOMEROOT.COMPANY:other-service:1234 - was unable to refresh its cache! status = Cannot execute request on any known server
com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
```

I am using Spring boot version 2.0.8

Can  any one please help me with this?

Comment: Thanks @SSK for helping me in formatting exception. Can you please share shortcut to format the exception while posting question in stack overflow

Comment: You need to add ``` at the start and at end of the block, you need to format. You can find more here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/3493829

Comment: Thanks SSK for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was in "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts" file. My hosts file got corrupted which was causing the issue.

Check the host that you are hitting, its entry is present in hosts file of system.